# Create Textfield in multiple position on view with button tap in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

friends

I have two button one for create textfield on view and other for remove textfield from view but every textfield is in different-2 position so please help me out thanks.
and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: can u show ur code......

Comment: Without showing your efforts no one is free to write code fro you.

Answer (score 0):

Here, i am providing you sample code. This code will generate 100(//or you can generate any no of textfield according to your requirements) textfield with random places and you can remove al this textfield by one click only...

```
UITextField *t[100];//declare it in .h file...

-(void)randomtextfield
{
int n = 100;
int temp;
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
  {
    int r = arc4random()%n;
    if(r != temp){
        temp = r;
        CGRect r1 = t[i].frame;      
        t[i].frame = t[temp].frame;
        t[temp].frame = r1; 

        n--;
        [self.view addSubview:t[i]];
     }

 }

}

-(IBAction)addtextfield
{
int x,y;
x=0;
y=0;

for (int i = 0; i<100;i++)
{

    t[i] = [[UITextField alloc]init];
    t[i].frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 30);
    t[i].borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleBezel;

    if(x<320)
    {
        x = x+100;
    }

    else
    {
        x=0;
    }

    if (y<480)
    {
        y= y+30;
    }

    else
    {
        y=0;
    }
  }
  [self randomtextfield];

 }



-(IBAction)removertextfield:(id)sender
{
  NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableSet alloc]initWithArray:[self.view subviews]];
   {
    [textfield removeFromSuperview];
   }
 [array release];
}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: i already use this code i dont want exacly this i show you my code what i want thanks for rpley

Comment: @jyoti: if you want resolution than make your question clear. My answer  is right for you question resolution..if you want something else than make it clear...I suggest you,Please ask question very clear..it will help you a lot..

Comment: Thanku you, I have to button + and - when user tap on + then textfield addes and when user tap on - then textfield remove from screen and if user want then he can create 100 textfield so i cannot assign position all the textfield so i want to create textfield in diff diff position. Thanks.

Comment: @jyoti : I updated my answer with code..it will full-fill  requirements...and accept answers if it's right for solution. It will also help you a lot...chill

Comment: It created many textfield on screen its not properly work its ok thanks I got the solution now I tried with table view its work but I have problem in this. can You help me out from that problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller, set up an array for the text fields -

.h -

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *myTextFields;
```

.m -

```
#define kScreenWidth                480.0 // or set this up elsewhere according to device, etc
#define kScreenHeight               320.0
#define kTextFieldWidth             150.0
#define kTextFieldHeight            36.0

@synthesize myTextFields;

-(id)init {

    self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        myTextFields = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}


-(IBAction)addTextField {

    CGFloat x = ((CGFloat) rand() / RAND_MAX) * (kScreenWidth - kTextFieldWidth);
    CGFloat y = ((CGFloat) rand() / RAND_MAX) * (kScreenHeight - kTextFieldHeight);

    UITextField *theTextField = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, kTextFieldWidth, kTextFieldHeight)] autorelease];

    theTextField.tag = [myTextFields count] + 1; // so you know which one is being edited

    // set up other text field properties here, like delegate, background, font, etc.

    [self.view addSubview:theTextField];
    [myTextFields addObject:theTextField];

}


-(IBAction)removeTextField {

    if (![myTextFields count]) return;

    UITextField *theTextField = [myTextFields lastObject];

    [theTextField removeFromSuperview];
    [myTextFields removeLastObject];

}
```

If you wanted none of the textFields to overlap, you'd have to do checking when you generate the random positions.